# Selecting objects from database

Tags: c#, .net, database, wpf, entity-framework

Currently, I am working on a WPF project which takes a data from database.

```
class Quizzes: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private long _id;
        private string _quizType = "";
        private string _quizName = "";

        [Key]
        public long QuizID
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }

            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("QuizID");
            }
        }

        public string QuizType
        {
            get
            {
                return _quizType;
            }

            set
            {
                _quizType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("QuizType");
            }
        }

        public string QuizName
        {
            get
            {
                return _quizName;
            }

            set
            {
                _quizName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("QuizName");
            }
        }

        public Quizzes(long id, string quizName, string quizType)
        {
            QuizID = id;
            QuizName = quizName;
            QuizType = quizType;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create an object from database columns

```
            Quizzes temp = (Quizzes)db.
            Quizzes
            .Where(c => c.QuizID == randomQuizId)
            .Select(u => new Quizes (u.QuizID, u.QuizName, u.QuizType));
```

This part calls an exception that says "Could not cast object type "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1 [Quizzes]" to type "Quizzes"
". I have a constructor in the "Quizzes" class, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have written `QuiZes` with one 'Z', but your class contains two. Do you have other such class or it is a typo?

[image]

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is not the main problem, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You query returns a collection of `Quizzes` and you are trying to assign it to one `Quizzes` instead of a `IEnumerable<Quizzes>`. You could modify the query to pick the one object that has the correct primary key using the `Find` method, the `First` method or the `Single` method. See [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework/single-singleordefault-first-firstordefault-in-entity-framework/) for a description of the difference between them.

```
Quizzes temp = (Quizzes)db.
        Quizzes
        .First(c => c.QuizID == randomQuizId)     
        .Select(u => new Quizes (u.QuizID, u.QuizName, u.QuizType));
```

To avoid confusion, it would be better if the class name was singular rather than plural, ie, `Quiz` instead of `Quizzes`.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking the answer as accepted.